# How to know the IP addresses of services on diferent nodes when provisioning?

Tags: chef-infra, digital-ocean, terraform

I provision using Terraform and Chef, with my infrastructure on Digital Ocean. On one node, I have Grafana. This node has a script that needs to know where is the MongoDB and Elasticsearch because it updates its dashboards.

I don't know which are the IPs of MongoDB or Elasticsearch, because they are on different nodes when provisioned.

How I can solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entirely Chef based answer is to use the Chef search API. This allows querying for nodes based on attributes, in this case probably `roles:mongo` or similar. Chef search is a relatively slow to converge system though, taking chef runs on both sides in the right order which can take several minutes. Newer, dedicated tools like Consul or Eureka can reconverge in milliseconds.

Comment: I'll take a look at Consul, it looks nice!